# Can WebExtensions be used on Firefox for Android

Tags: android, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions, firefox-android

[WebExtensions are for desktop Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions), but now I have a doubt: Are WebExtensions also for the Firefox for Android browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, WebExtensions can be used for [Extensions for Firefox for Android](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Firefox_for_Android?document_saved=true).<sup>1</sup>  Primary support is available starting with Firefox for Android version 48. However, there is support for a smaller set of APIs then are available on desktop Firefox.  You can see the list of available APIs on MDN's [Browser support for JavaScript APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Browser_support_for_JavaScript_APIs) page. The column you are interested in is "Firefox for Android".

---

1. I just updated the page to explicitly state that WebExtensions are possible and preferred. You may have to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F5</kbd> to see the updated page.

Comment: Thank you very much, particularly for the second link, that's what I needed! I am going to abandon SDK and use definitively WE because it has been said that SDK residual  lifetime has to be short - something like end of 2017

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help. Moving to WebExtensions is a good choice. Yes, the [*plan* is that all extensions other than WebExtensions will not be permitted to be run in Firefox by the end of 2017](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2016/11/23/add-ons-in-2017/) in release versions of Firefox.